# Missing methods in SheetService class

Tags: ruby, google-sheets-api

There are a few methods in this class described in the documentation that do not exist when I actually try to use them:

- append_spreadsheet_value
- batch_clear_values
- batch_spreadsheet_value_clear_by_data_filter
- batch_spreadsheet_get_by_data_filter
- batch_spreadsheet_update_by_data_filter
- clear_values
- get_spreadsheet_by_data_filter
- get_spreadsheet_developer_metadatum
- search_developer_metadatum_developer_metadata

The source code for the class:

- `C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\google-api-client-0.9.9\generated\google\apis\sheets_v4`

doesn't show any sign of these methods.

Is the code for these methods supposed to be located somewhere else, is the missing code a big oversight, or is there some other explanation for these methods not working?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have installed an extremely old version of this gem (0.9.9 - June 09, 2016).

The [latest one is 0.24.3](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-api-client/) (October 09, 2018), and those methods are present in the GitHub repository also:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/711dfb83b33c03535076917726956584d5c8bf9a/generated/google/apis/sheets_v4/service.rb#L390

Comment: One of things I was thinking is that it might be a gem version thing, but I didn't think of looking on the google-api-client page to find out which version I needed for some stupid reason, and who knows why I have such an old version in the first place. Of course, to be extra confusing, the latest version has a lower number than the old one.

Comment: I also had this issue: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1736

Comment: Now I get this: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2332:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32, because mime-types-3.2.2 conflicts with mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0) (Gem::ConflictError). Everything should just be the same version forever and I wouldn't have all these problems.

Comment: This is why you want to use Bundler, because in most cases it is able to resolve such conflicts automatically. Just create a Gemfile with the gems you need and run `bundle install`, and it takes care of it for you.

Comment: I do use bundler, but I find it pretty confusing. I guess I should study it so I stop getting error messages like this:  C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2332:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32, because mime-types-3.2.2 conflicts with mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0) (Gem::ConflictError)